# Software to make blueprints from SketchUp Make (not Pro?)

Tags: cad

Is anyone familiar with software that will take a SketchUp  model and allow you to create blueprint files from it (2D floor plans)?

SketchUp Pro includes LayOut which does this. However, it's $700. Though reasonable for someone that does this for a living, this is a one-time thing for me and I can't see ever needed this particular feature again making the $700 price a bit steep.

I was hoping there are some less expensive 3rd party programs designed just for this, but I haven't had much luck finding anything.